# Is there a way to put blank lines only before annotated fields in IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, formatting

Is there a way to put blank lines only before annotated fields in IDEA by code formatting.

for example . after format  I would like to my code to looks like this.

```
public class A{

   @Id
   private int id;
   private String firstname;
   private String lastname;

   @Column
   private int age;
   private int foo;
   private int boo;

   @Column
   private int a;
}
```

I don't want to do it manually each time. 
IDEA version is 2017.1.

Thanks.

Comment: All possible options seem to be in Settings > Editor > Code Style > Java > Blank Lines. But no option only for annotated fields. If you think it useful maybe you can add it [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA) as a feature request.

Comment: I did
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-172095

Comment: I think this is a common problem.